# How to convert High bitrate MP3 to lower rate using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bitrate

We want to convert 320kbps mp3 file to 128kbps mp3 so currently we are using below ffmpeg command but its not working.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 5 output.mp3
```

**Result:**-the output bitrate same as input mp3.

And we are following the FFmpeg Encoding guideline for that here is the link :- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3

so please suggest any solution.

Comment: Do you have a link or name to the (Android) FFmpeg build you're using?

Comment: After years of FFmpeg usage I arrogantly didn't need to check how to set audio bitrate - I can just tell you... After reading your link now I see you were looking at **Variable BitRate** (VBR) settings where `-qscale:a 5` does aim for average bitrate of around 130kbps. Anycase your question sounds like really you want a **Constant BitRate** (CBR) of 128kbps. PS: I wanted to know your FFmpeg build because you can't input 320kbps with setting `-qscale:a 5` and get output of exact same 320kbps. What's wrong with it? I want to check...

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to Android, and about ffmpeg in general.  Suggest removing `android` tag and updating title.

Answer (score 35):

I tried your shown command (tested on Windows / commandline) :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 5 output.mp3
```

**Result** : It works for me. However the `-qscale:a 5` makes FFmpeg decide on an average bitrate for you. With one (320k) MP3 file I got it giving a close convert of **134kbps**. This is [**expected**](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) since :

> ```
> lame option   Average kbit/s  Bitrate range kbit/s    ffmpeg option
>    -V 5             130           120-150                -q:a 5
> ```

**Solution** : 
Instead of making the internal mp3 frames hold different bitrates (that vary to acommodate the "current" perceived audio, *eg:* think "silent" parts using smaller rate of bits/bytes compared to "busy" audio parts), so just set a **constant** bitrate of **128kbps** as you need.

I would just set it to constant **128kbps** manually and explicitly with :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k output.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but we have tried your given command but in the output log audio bitrates is 320 kbps after conversion.so and I have tried using android FFmpegAndroid library.so its not working for us.

Comment: Below is the log.but the bitrates of mp3 is 320Kbps
Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/AUD_1490697495080.mp3':
Metadata:
    TIT2 :Jab Tak
    TALB :MS Dhoni
    TPE1 :Armaan
    TSSE :Lavf56.4.101
Stream #0:1: Audio:mp3,44100 Hz,stereo,320 kb/s
frame=1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=1470kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate=802.2kbits/s

Comment: So output file `AUD_1490697495080.mp3` is a **different** name to the input file name, right? I mean afterwards you have two separate files that are both 320k, is that correct? I'm trying to visualize your issue and if YES about two files @ 320k then your result could only happen if used `-codec:a copy` instead of `-codec:a libmp3lame`... This is why I need to know your exact FFmpeg build (**got a link**?) to test exact same thing because maybe you have a buggy version....

Comment: for me 20MB mp3 converted to 3.6 MB file. thanks alot

Comment: Error: "Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container".  Clearly we need some way to tell ffmpeg that it's audio only.  Any ideas?

Comment: `-map 0:0` seems to fix it.  Why is that not the default?

Comment: @Jake How to reproduce that error? MP3 is not a container so it can't have been from `-i input.mp3`.

Comment: @VC.One it was a `.m4a` file.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message. This works okay `ffmpeg -i test.m4a -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 5 test.mp3`. I don't know why H264 video codec was mentioned by FFmpeg if you used an audio-only file (and not a renamed MP4)...

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -b:a 80k output.m4a`.  `Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))`.  The `mjpeg` 'stream' I think is just cover art.

Answer (score 9):

I use this shellscript in order to not visit this stackoverflow-page over and over again :)

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ ! -n $1 ]] && { 
    echo "Usage: mp3convert <input.mp3> <output.mp3> <bitrate:56/96/128/256> <channels> <samplerate>"
    exit 0
}
set -x # print next command
ffmpeg -i "$1" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a "$3"k -ac "$4" -ar $5 "$2"
```

Comment: The -ar achieved what I was expecting from -b:a

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your version of FFmpeg has `libmp3lame` enabled. The selected answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```sh
ffmpeg -v debug -i "input.mp3" -c:a libmp3lame \
   -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn "output.mp3"
```

`-ac 2` - output has 2 (stereo) audio channels
`-ar 44100` - sample rate of 44100Hz, which is ideal for high quality music.

Although, in 2022 I wouldn't recommend converting to 128kbps since storage space is much more cheap and abundant nowadays.

I think `-b:a 192k` strikes the best balance between compression and quality for most people (unless you're an audiophile with $1000 headphones, and even then you'd be better off using FLAC anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22:

```
$ ffmpeg -v debug -i "input.file" -c:libmp3lame -b:a 32k \
             -ac 1 -ar 44100 -vn "out.file"
```

However Ubuntu 18 gives an error, so the working command:

```
$ ffmpeg    -i rassel.mp3     \
             -codec:a libmp3lame    -b:a 32k  \
              -ar 44100    -ac 1     rassel-out.mp3
```